# How to verify digital signature with a file in Java?

Tags: java, hash, cryptography, digital-signature, asn.1

I'm complete beginner in the world of cryptography. I have 2 files - one of them is a digital signature(p7s, signedData) and file which I should verify signature with. The question is how can I do that using Java? Firstly I thought that I can do like this

```
String rawString = ASN1ObjectIdentifier.fromByteArray(bytesArray).toString();

String rawStringForSurname = rawString.substring(rawString.indexOf("2.5.4.4,") + 9, rawString.length());
String signSurname = rawStringForSurname.substring(0, rawStringForSurname.indexOf("]"));


String rawStringForGivenName = rawString.substring(rawString.indexOf("2.5.4.42,") + 10, rawString.length());
String signGivenName = rawStringForGivenName.substring(0, rawStringForGivenName.indexOf("]"));
```

Which is awful, obviously. My input data is only intended to have one file (p7s file, which is later decoded to ASN.1 and verifies surname and fullName with author's (data from outside, string)). Surprisingly it turned out, that I should have a file which I should verify sign with as well. I know that there's strange hashcodes logic(that file is intact and the sign is related EXACTLY to the file). The question is how can I retrieve this data from file and sign? And what exactly should I compare in order to accept or reject it? The library I use is Bouncy Castle.

Answer (score 0):

### I use [Demoiselle Framework](https://github.com/demoiselle/framework) to solve this in my project.

Especially the [Signer Part](https://github.com/demoiselle/signer)

### Maybe this share of code can help you too

For Example:

```java

```
    package stackoverflow.my.pack;

    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.security.PrivateKey;
    import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate;
    import org.demoiselle.signer.policy.engine.factory.PolicyFactory.Policies;
    import org.demoiselle.signer.policy.impl.cades.factory.PKCS7Factory;
    import org.demoiselle.signer.policy.impl.cades.pkcs7.PKCS7Signer;

    public class MySigner {
        private static PKCS7Signer signerLoader() {
            PKCS7Signer signer = PKCS7Factory.getInstance().factoryDefault();
            PrivateKey pk = MyReader.getPrivateKey();// Create some method to get your PK
            signer.setPrivateKey(pk);

            X509Certificate certificate = MyReader.getMyPublicKey();// Create some method to get your Pub
            signer.setCertificates((Certificate[]) Arrays.asList(certificate).toArray());

            if (is2048(privateKey)) {
                signer.setSignaturePolicy(Policies.AD_RB_CADES_2_2);
            } else {
                signer.setSignaturePolicy(Policies.AD_RB_CADES_1_1);
            }
            return signer;
        }

        public static byte[] myMethodToSign(byte[] fileToBeSigned) throws MySignerException {
            PKCS7Signer signer = signerLoader();
            return signer.doHashSign(fileToBeSigned);
        }
    }
```

```

Demoiselle use BouncyCastle too, you can see their sign method to helps you.
You have to load your PK, add BouncyCastle as your Provider, get your SignPolicy Information, validate certificate chain, get a data generator and build your attribute table.
[The way Demoiselle do.](https://github.com/demoiselle/signer/blob/7434733096a21012c4dfb8a3d3f2f959c81e9366/policy-impl-cades/src/main/java/org/demoiselle/signer/policy/impl/cades/pkcs7/impl/CAdESSigner.java)

If you want to see an example of using their Signer:
https://github.com/demoiselle/signer/blob/master/signer-examples/src/main/java/org/demoiselle/signer/signer/examples/Signer.java